# iCloud locate last tracked position?

Tags: icloud, find-my-iphone

I've lost my iPhone, and its power has run out.

Is it possible to use iCloud to locate where it was last detected?

Comment: Did you enable Find your Phone?

Answer (score 1):

That is only possible for the last 24 hours

> If the device was recently online, you also see the time it was last located. If the device has been offline for over 24 hours, you see “Offline.”

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2698?locale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

- You need to enable function "Find My iPhone" (inside  Settings>iCloud).
- Of course, "Location" service (inside Settings>Privacy) also need to be enabled too. 
  [image: Find My iPhone on iOS 9]